# When using scala path dependent type as function codomain, why is it impossible to add alias for that function?

Tags: scala, dependent-type, existential-type, path-dependent-type, scala-2.13

Here is a simple example:

```
trait Proposition[T] {
  type Repr = T
}

trait Scope {

  type OUT

  type Consequent = Proposition[_ <: OUT]

  abstract class Proof[-I, +P <: Consequent] {
    final def instanceFor(v: I): P#Repr = ???
    final def apply(v: I): P#Repr = instanceFor(v)
  }
}
```

This gives the compilation error:

```
[Error] ....scala:44: type mismatch;
 found   : _$1(in type Consequent)
 required: (some other)_$1(in type Consequent)
```

Where does this `(some other)` come from? Is it a compiler bug caused by a clear rule of type selection (which should be theoretically solved in scala 3)?

**UPDATE 1** Sorry I just realised that `P#Repr` should not be called type selection, which should only refers to `val p: P;p.Repr`, now it added even more confusion because:

- I don't even know the name of this grammar, yet I kept using it for a long time
- It is not even defined in DOT calculus. So scala 3 support is questionable

Comment: Not sure if this is a bug, but this is probably a consequence of type projections being too wide.

Comment: What does that mean? also type projection is not a DOT calculus grammar

Comment: That `P#Repr` is usually meaningless, that is why it was unsound and that is why it was removed.

Comment: Yeah, now I've found a long list of discussion regarding its soundness, so I'll just need to figure out a circumvention of it

Comment: @tribbloid I can't reproduce in 2.13.6 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/FfC8vI7fQjeaai5xLLfLiQ/1 What's your version of Scala?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Well, type projections are not so meaningless. They are one of two sorts of type-level calculations in Scala 2 (the other sort is type classes). In some sense match types replace type projections in this role in Scala 3 (although on value level match types work currently not so well). Type projections is a primary notion in specification of Scala 2 (I guess there is no spec of Scala 3 yet), for example path-dependent types etc. are defined via type projections. Unsoundness of type projections outside using along with intersection types and lower bounds is disputable.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Did you manage to reproduce?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez And besides that type projections remain in Scala 3. Type projections on an abstract type are banned.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Sorry you are right, I simplify the example which seems to make the compiler easier to figure out. Let me modify it a bit.

Comment: Type projection as an extension called gDOT seems to be proven: https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty-feature-requests/issues/14. For the moment we still need a mechanical way to circumvent it using other features

Comment: @DmytroMitin you know I am always on mobile :) so no, I couldn't reproduce it. AFAIK _(but I don't know too much about it)_ path-dependent types and type projections are different things and the latter were planned to be removed from the language, but they manage to prove the soundness of a more simplified version of them; which again AFAIK doesn't cover this use case since `P#Repr` is a projection on an abstract type AFAIK, but I may be wrong.

Comment: I'm really sorry the example was now fixed. https://scastie.scala-lang.org/zxDRTVxFT3yZZMrUQy2akA

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Path-dependent types and type projections are not completely different things because the latter are partial case of the former (at least in Scala 2). `p.Repr` is `p.type#Repr` by definition (according to the spec). So path-dependent types are defined in terms of type projections and singleton types.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a bug.

I minimized your code till

```
trait Proposition[T] {
  type Repr = T
}

trait Scope {
  type Consequent = Proposition[_]

  abstract class Proof[P <: Consequent] {
    val instanceFor: P#Repr = ??? // doesn't compile
      // type mismatch;
      // found   : Proof.this.instanceFor.type (with underlying type _$1)
      // required: _$1
  }
}
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/DNRby7JGRc2TPZuwIM8ROA/1 (Scala 2.13.6)

So we can't even declare a single variable of type `P#Repr`.

It seems similar to bugs:

- [2346. Type error with type members and existential types in type bounds](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/2346) (open since 11 Sep 2009, Scala 2.8.0)
- [11910. Type constructor `V` parameterized with a type `A` including a member type `T` does not resolve `T` when parameterized with a concrete subtype of `A`](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11910)

---

> Where does this `(some other)` come from?

It comes from *skolemization* of an existential type

https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#existential-types

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form

`Proposition[_]` is a shorthand for `Proposition[T] forSome { type T <: OUT }`. If you replace `Proposition[_]` with the latter then the error message will be

```
type mismatch;
 found   : T(in type Consequent)
 required: (some other)T(in type Consequent)
      final def apply(v: I): P#Repr = instanceFor(v)
```

Comment: Good to know, too bad we can't even verify if the problem is addressed by the latest compiler or not, until much later

Comment: Also, I didn't even use the existential type feature (which was also dropped in scala 3), are you referring to a more specific case?

Comment: Sorry your last part of the answer addressed the terminology. It is not dropped in scala 3, so ideally it should be given a new name

Comment: @tribbloid *"too bad we can't even verify if the problem is addressed by the latest compiler"* Actually we can. It's enough to [replace](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/master/compiler/src/dotty/tools/dotc/core/CheckRealizable.scala#L127) `if (!isConcrete(tp)) NotConcrete` with `if (!isConcrete(tp)) Realizable` (now we allow `P#Repr`) and such patched compiler compiles the code without errors (so it can't see other problems like `type mismatch`).

Comment: by "the latest" I mean scala 3.x

Comment: hmmm... so you did change on top of scala 3, why do they keep changing the syntax of the language? The last time I checked there is no type projection at all

Comment: I see what you are doing here .... you are overriding a core axiom of scala3's calculus! (the error message: P is not a legal path clearly indicates this) in this case I think it will be very hard to convince the maintainer to relax it. We may still need to wait for full acknowledgement of gDOT